# what is the meaning of this statement in PHP

Tags: php

.

```
$row['NO'] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)"        onClick="openmywindow(\''.$row['bcd'].'\',\''.$row['gfh'].'\',\''.$row['test2'].'\',\''.$_REQUEST['test1'].'\')">'.$row['abc'].'</a>'
```

In the above statement, what is the meaning of escaping the values in that manner such as '\'. How can i learn this?
In the above statement i want to replace the php variable `$row['TEST2']` with a static value 'OPEN', but i am getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$row['NO'] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="openmywindow(\''.$row['bcd'].'\',\''.$row['gfh'].'\',\'OPEN\',\''.$_REQUEST['test1'].'\')">'.$row['abc'].'</a>';
```

Because the escaping is very confusing it might be better to use HEREDOC:

```
$row['NO'] =<<<EOC;
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="openmywindow('$row[bcd]','$row[gfh]','OPEN','$_REQUEST[test1].')">$row[abc]</a>
EOC;
```

More about strings [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php) (including escaping and heredoc).

PS: Do not use `$_REQUEST`. Instead use `$_GET` or `$_POST` (the one that is appropriate here.)

Answer (score 1):

> In the above statement what is the
>   meaning of escaping the values in that
>   manner suchas '\'.How can we learn
>   this

Have a look at this tutorial :)

[PHP and Escaping](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html)

For the error, make sure that you escape the strings correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would suggest that you do instead of escaping + concatenating strings  :

```
$html = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"openmywindow('%s','%s','%s',%s');\">%s</a>";
$row['NO'] = sprintf($html, 
    $row['bcd'], 
    $row['gfh'],
    $row['test2'],
    $_REQUEST['test1'],
    $row['abc']
);
```

And then replace whatever you need to replace... Read the manual about [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for more details.

Also, if any argument after `$html` contain `'` chars, you must call [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on those arguments.

** **UPDATE** **

About `$_REQUEST`, read [here](http://devlog.info/2010/02/04/why-php-request-array-is-dangerous/) why it is not recommended to use it.

Comment: You forget escaping the double quotes, fixed that for you ;)